# Resful name API for multiple key objects

Tags: java, rest, api, api-design

We are implementing an API and we want to follow best practices for naming the endpoints. However, during the design, we have found a challenge. We have some objects where the key to the objects is a combination of three keys: key1, key2, key3.

We have been following for other objects (e.g. orders) the pattern:

```
 api/orders?fiter1=value1&filter2=value2  # To retrieve the list of orders that futfill al the filters.  
 api/orders/{key}   # To retrieve an spepcific order
```

But, what happens if the key is actually a combined key in the database, for example, the combination of day and name of the person for example?

Some developers follow this approach:

1/

```
 api/order?day=2017-05-20&name=Bob  # This approach I don't like it because the endpoints are singular.
```

2/

```
 api/orders/{month}/{name}  # Don't like it because is really nasty
```

I have seen a different approach, that I like:

```
 api/orders/{date:name}
```

In this idea, the key is created as a combination of both properties. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I have reread your question three times, and I still don't understand it. If you're loading orders for a specific customer for a specific day, just do `api/orders?day=2017-05-20&customer=Bob` since you seem to dislike (and you're right) the singular form. But it's so obvious that I suppose that there is something else in your question, but what?...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem with this approach that you are saying `api/orders?day=2017-05-20&customer=Bob` is that you will always retrieve one object wrapper into a list, when I just one to retrieve one single object.

Comment: What if there are multiple orders for the same person in a given day? Anyway, if in a given domain, it is natural that there would always be one and one only order, than what's wrong with your first suggestion, *“api/order?day=2017-05-20&name=Bob”*?

Comment: This is only an example, the main point is that I have a composite id and I don't know the best way to design an endpoint to retrieve only one object without needs to wrapper it into a list.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Well, let's wait, maybe somebody here understands it and will give you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST doesn't constrain your resource identifiers, beyond the expectation that they will satisfy the production rules described in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).  The machines just don't care.  So any spelling that will satisfy your local code review is *fine*.

Some spellings are more convenient than others, because they encode information that can easily be described by a [URI template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570).

Using paths (`api/orders/{month}/{name}`) can be convenient when the identifier hierarchy maps well to your resource hierarchy, and you want to use [dot segments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) to describe identifiers.

```
api/orders/{month}/{name} + xx -> api/orders/{month}
```

Using query parameters can be convenient on the web, because HTML production rules allow us to use a form as a sort of poor man's URI template.  Web browsers (and other HTML capable tools) already know how to build URI like `api/order?day=2017-05-20&name=Bob`.

```
api/orders/{date}:{name}
```

That's also perfectly fine (assuming you properly escape any reserved characters that happen to occur in {date} or {name}.  Note that, from the perspective of a generic consumer, this example uri has three path segments, not four:

```
api/orders/{date}:{name} + .. -> api/orders
```

This syntax is also very close to a different idea, called [Path Style parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2.7) (sometimes also referred to as Matrix parameters), which uses semi colons to delimit key value pairs

```
api/orders/{;date,name}
```

Level 3 compliant template processors should be able to correctly resolve a URI template that includes path style parameters.